# How to query W|A, to get a list of asymmetric, bicubic and $3$-edge colorable graphs?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, wolfram-alpha-queries

I'm interested in finding graphs with certain properties, like [the smallest cubic bipartite asymmetric graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1109733/19341). While working on a related graph-theoretic problem, concerning [edge-colrings](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1121030/19341), I came along  [Georges Graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GeorgesGraph) at Wolfram|Alpha.

It shows a nice collection of properties of the graph:

asymmetric  |  bicolorable  |  biconnected  |  bicubic  |  bipartite  |  bridgeless  |  class 1  |  connected  |  cubic  |  cyclic  |  local  |  noncayley  |  noneulerian  |  nonhamiltonian  |  nonplanar  |  perfect  |  perfect matching  |  regular  |  square-free  |  traceable  |  triangle-free  |  weakly regular

So I'm interested if it's possible to search Wolfram|Alpha for graph with certain properties.

How to build a query, that returns a list of graphs that are asymmetric, bicubic and $3$-edge colorable i.e. they have chromatic index $3$?

Other ways to get that list are also welcome..

Comment: Is this question about how to query W|A from within Mathematica or using the site/app? The latter is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries as the link indicates it's about the site. Sorry for posting an off-topic question. Do you know if W|A has a support forum where my question would fit?

Comment: http://community.wolfram.com/content?curTag=wolfram%20alpha

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using the Wolfram|Alpha site without involving Mathematica.

Comment: I would ask the poser to re-frame the (valuable) question in terms of *Mathematica*, not *Wolfram|Alpha*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork since I don't have Mathematica, please feel free to edit my question. Thanks for your support...

Comment: Cross-posted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/429851?p_p_auth=5nF4XEuY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Mathematica*, however, the search is simple, for instance:

```
GraphData[{"Bicubic", "Asymmetric", "Planar"}]
```

(*
{{"Cubic", {24, 3}}, {"Cubic", {54, 1}}, {"CubicPolyhedral", 
  9}, {"CubicPolyhedral", 18}, {"CubicPolyhedral", 
  42}, {"CubicPolyhedral", 
  50}, "GreatRhombicosidodecahedralGraph", \
"GreatRhombicuboctahedralGraph", {"Prism", 6}, {"Prism", 8}, {"Prism",
   10}, {"Prism", 12}, {"Prism", 14}, {"Prism", 16}, {"Prism", 
  18}, {"Prism", 20}, "TruncatedOctahedralGraph"}
*)

(I didn't see a simple property describing "3-colorable", but perhaps such a term can be constructed from other basic properties.)

Comment: Since you included "planar", you already included "3-edge colorable", since there is a simple mapping from 4-face colorable, due to the 4-color theorem, to a 3-coloring of the edges. Thanks for your list. Which of those has the least count of vertices? "Prism,6"?

Comment: "Prism,6" is asymmetric? Really?

Comment: @draks It's not edge transitive, so it's not symmetric.